# Concatenate Strings to a Vector of Strings

Tags: julia

I have a string vector

```
faces = ["bold", "ital", "code"]

3-element Vector{String}:
 "bold"
 "ital"
 "code"
```

and I have a scalar `String`

```
"The font face is "
```

that I want to combine to a `Vector{String}`

```
["The font face is bold", "The font face is ital", "The font face is code"]
```

I could swear I did this before using `$faces`, but I can't remember how.

---

*Additional clarification*:
I am looking for a way to insert the elements of the vector into the string. So, while `"The font face is " .* faces` works for this example I am looking (also) for the solution that puts the vector values inside the string. A solution that would work like

```
String.("The font face is $(faces)")
```

Comment: Try `str .* faces`, where `str` is your scalar string.

Comment: Ah, dammit I made mistake in the question. I'll edit it.

Comment: Not sure I understand the clarification - does `["The font face is $f" for f ∈ faces]` count?

Comment: Julia Strings are immutable, so any solution you get will be equivalent to `str .* faces` in the sense that you'll be creating new concatenated strings. There's no such thing as "inserting the elements of the vector into the string".

Comment: @NilsGudat yes, the array comprehension does count. Put it as an answer. (It's still what I thought I remember - maybe I just remember incorrectly.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the last line of your question, may be you had a patttern like this in mind:

```
julia> string.("The font face is ", faces)
3-element Vector{String}:
 "The font face is bold"
 "The font face is ital"
 "The font face is code"
```

Semantically, this and the `.*` solution and the map solution are ultimately doing the same thing, but perhaps you have a preference for this syntax.

Answer (score 6):

```
faces = ["bold", "ital", "code"]
str = "The font face is "

map(x -> str*x, faces)
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is an option as well:

```
["The font face is $f" for f ∈ faces]
```

This answer is from Nils Gudat in the comments above. (Happy to remove it if he wants to post it.)